# How to clear input field whitespace in live ajax search after I click on a result

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a simple ajax live search script using PHP jQuery and ajax. It all works great but the input box does not clear completely so the results box doesn't disappear unless I manually clear it..

JS -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.search-box input[type="text"]').on("keyup input", function(){
                /* Get input value on change */
                var inputVal = $(this).val();
                var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result");
                if(inputVal.length){
                    $.get("backend-search.php", {term: inputVal}).done(function(data){
                        // Display the returned data in browser
                        resultDropdown.html(data);
                    });

                } else{
                    resultDropdown.empty();
                }
            });

            // Set search input value on click of result item
            $(document).on("click", ".result", function(){
                $(this).parents(".search-box").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
                $(this).parent(".result").empty();

            });
        });
    </script>
```

PHP -

```
$user = $_GET['user'];

$term = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['term']);
if(isset($term)){
// Attempt select query execution
$sql = "SELECT * FROM prospects WHERE dealer_name LIKE '" . $term . "%'";
if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $dealer_name = $row['dealer_name'];
            echo "<form method='post' class='editForm'>
             <input type='hidden' name='dealer' value='$dealer_name'/>
                        <input type='submit' id='subDealer' value='$dealer_name'/>
                    </form>";
        }
        // Close result set
    } else{
        echo "<p>No matches found</p>";
    }
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($conn);
}
}
```

HTML -

```
 <div class="search-box">
     <input type="text" id="searchBox" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search dealer..." />
     <div class="result"></div>
 </div>
```

Like it said it all works but there is blank whitespace in the input field (#searchBox) which will not allow the .result to clear..

Thanks!

Comment: where is there any php involved?

Comment: Sorry Ill add it real quick

Comment: I can get *where* is your problem, is in this if `if(inputVal.length){` ? Or in the click event `$(this).parent(".result").empty();` ?

Comment: If you want remove whitespace at the start and end of your value, you can use **trim()**, **$(this).val().trim()**

Comment: @Jeff yes exactly

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown not sure, the results box disappears when the input field clears but clicking on the results doesnt clear the whitespace just the text

Comment: If **trim()** doesn't work, try to replace char '\t' with '' like that : **$(this).val().replace(/\t/g, "")**

Comment: I think you need to write `$(this).parents(".search-box").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text().trim());`

Comment: @Siva thanks this clears the input field but now but the results doesnt disappear without me clicking into the input field and clicking backspace once

Comment: I think I got it. Replace this line `$(this).parent(".result").empty();` with `$(this).empty();` Because you are already binding click handler to the result

Comment: @Siva that worked in clearing everything except now the form button doesn't load the content lol. gotta love programming!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below snippet

```
// Set search input value on click of result item
$(document).on("click", ".result", function(){
    $(this).parents(".search-box").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text().trim());
});


$(document).on('click', 'input[type=submit]', function() {
   // This is NOT the best practice. But it works. Try to change your implementation to a better one!
   setTimeout(function() {
       $('.result').empty();
   }, 1000);
   return true;
}
```

Comment: This fixes my issue but now get "Form submission canceled because the form is not connected"

Comment: Well, it is hard to debug code in my mind :P. So tell me, Was it working before? And looks like `action` attribute of the form is missing.

Comment: Sorry ya everything worked except clearing the input field. It seems when I change  $(this).parent(".result").empty(); to this -  $(this).empty(); it disconnects the form somehow

Comment: I understood the problem. Now what happens here is before sending the `form` post, the `.result` div is getting cleared. Before it wasn't happening because it wasn't actually emptying the `.result` div. Now tell me, when do you want to clear the div and why do you want to clear the div ?

Comment: Ahh ya sorry for the horrible explanation.. Yes I would like to click the form element in results then it clear the results.. The reason is the results the is dropdown, once I find the result I want and click it I have the php load which means I no longer need to see the results until I do another search.. You are correct the results seem to be removed before the form loads after the button click..

Comment: Well then, how about this? You need to clear the `.result` div only when you click back in the input field. So it will be like, the user types something in input. The result is populated. When the user clicks on the result, input field is cleared. Now when user clicks on the form, it displays something else. When the user again clicks back on input field, you can clear the result. For this you need to add `mouseup` event listener as well. like `$('.search-box input[type="text"]').on("keyup input mouseup", function(){ // etc ` If this is okay, let me know I will update the answer.

Comment: And you need to remove this line ` $(this).empty();`

Comment: Ok so im confused, I dont want to click back into the search box to clear results, I would like the results to be removed once the form button is clicked as thats when the php script loads.. Is thatw hat your sayng?

Comment: Well, I have updated the answer based on your requirement. Please try and let me know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145910/discussion-between-siva-and-ryan-d).

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery trim() function

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.search-box input[type="text"]').on("keyup input", function(){
                    /* Get input value on change */
                    var inputVal1 = $(this).val();
                    var inputVal = $.trim(inputVal1);
                    var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result");
                    if(inputVal.length){
                        $.get("backend-search.php", {term: inputVal}).done(function(data){
                            // Display the returned data in browser
                            resultDropdown.html(data);
                        });

                    } else{
                        resultDropdown.empty();
                    }
                });

                // Set search input value on click of result item
                $(document).on("click", ".result", function(){
                    $(this).parents(".search-box").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
                    $(this).parent(".result").empty();

                });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Thanks but still get same result, a bunch of blank whitespace in field